# ENOENT: no such file or directory, bower_components\bootstrap\js\transition.js'

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm just starting out with ember JS and my basic application seemed to be working like a charm, till I decided to add ember-cli-simple-auth through the ember cli. Since I have added this, I'm getting the error in the title and I have no clue how. 
I know there is not much detail I have provided, but this is all I can think of. I tried uninstalling the ember-cli-simple-auth library but it doesn't help. Any help here would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you run `bower install`? If not run it. If you already have, try to remove the `bower_components` folder completely and run `bower install` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicate

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, bower_components\bootstrap\js\transition.js'

there is no directory called *bower_components*, that means the dependencies are not installed.

To install dependencies, run

```
> bower install
```

command on the terminal from the root directory of the project where `bower.json` file is located.

This will install all the front-end dependencies in the *bower_components* folder.

Comment: recently facing the same issue..this time its [link](https://imgur.com/a/8tbVJ)..... some where i noticed like Yarn downloads bootstrap differently and also removed bootstrap from bower components in ember-cli..could some one let me know more details on it